# What is the order of memory allocation when demand exceeds single numa node

Tags: c, linux, kernel, numa

With a 4 numa node linux server(128G each), I was trying to allocate 300G memory by kmalloc_node(2) to specify the allocation start node. Could any great master tell me what is the order of allocation along with the remaining nodes when node2's memory runs out? Many thanks!

I have tried to use numactl to observe the memory remaining of each node, but it changed each time...